# Create dynamic UI in .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a .Net web application. It is a form and the contents like the text, drop downs, check boxes change often so i don't want to create the markup in ascx file. I want to create them dynamically like from an xml or something like that.

Can any one please advise of what is the best method to achieve my scenario ? Can i use XAML in web application ? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a database in the background that you can use to store what fields should currently be shown on the page? doesn't matter a whole lot but can make editing what fields show up easier than manually writing XML

Answer (score 1):

if you add a runat="server" tag to your form, then you can manipulate its controls programmatically at the server-side.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
```

Then in your server-side code just do something like this

```
var lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "this is my label";
form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: that is fine..my question is where should i store the UI information ? in a XML ? what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: I've stored it in data tables before, I suppose it depends on what controls the dynamic nature of the UI elements. If its controlled by site administrators, you could store it to a database. XML is fine, and if you choose XML then you could adopt an XSLT approach for converting your XML into html.